# DNS returns IP addresses of non-existent URLs

Tags: server, dns, ping

On "Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS" both **ping** and a python3.8 script with **dnspython** 1.16.0 return IP adresses of URLs which do not exist. With "Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS" under Windows 10 WSL, these errors do not occur. These bugs occur on a dedicated server where several apache2.4 vhosts are running. I get e.g.:

```
ping akjdsla.com -c 1
  PING akjdsla.com.com (45.11.57.36) 56(84) bytes of data.
  64 bytes from comcomproxy1.com.com (45.11.57.36): icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=37.5 ms
  --- akjdsla.com.com ping statistics ---
  1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
  rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 37.460/37.460/37.460/0.000 ms
```

but

```
nslookup akjdsla.com
  Server:         127.0.0.53
  Address:        127.0.0.53#53
  ** server can't find akjdsla.com: NXDOMAIN

nslookup akjdsla.com dns.google
   Server:         dns.google
   Address:        2001:4860:4860::8888#53
   ** server can't find akjdsla.com: NXDOMAIN
```

and

```
dig akjdsla.com
  ; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> akjdsla.com
  ;; global options: +cmd
  ;; Got answer:
  ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 33872
  ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
  
  ;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
  ; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
  ;; QUESTION SECTION:
  ;akjdsla.com.                   IN      A
  
  ;; Query time: 0 msec
  ;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
  ;; WHEN: Thu Mar 17 16:17:49 CET 2022
  ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 40
```

So **nslookup** and **dig** work as expected, while **ping** and **dnspython** fail. The behaviour depends on the queried toplevel domain: If an IP is returned for a non-existent URL, it will always be the same IP for certain TLDs. I get:

```
com   45.11.57.36      comcomproxy1.com.com
de    54.153.56.183    ec2-54-153-56-183.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
eu    54.153.56.183    ec2-54-153-56-183.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
org   34.206.39.153    ec2-34-206-39-153.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

On the other hand: For the TLDs **net**, edu, fr, ca, biz, **ping** and **dnspython recognize** when an URL is **non-existent**. dnspython crashes if a non-existent URL with TLD **it** is queried.

One reader suggested that one should consider the possibility that nameservers might post "fake IPs" for non-existent domains to advertise their own service. In this case, the IPs should change with the nameservers but they do not. The site behind "comcomproxy1.com.com" is blocked by "uBlock Origin" due to badware risk. ec2-34-206-39-153.compute-1.amazonaws.com is redirected to https://aws.amazon.com/. ec2-54-153-56-183.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com does not lead to a HTTPS site. Furthermore, this does not explain the different behaviour of different DNS-querying.programs. Therefore, the advertising hypothesis doesn't seem very plausible to me.

We host .com, .de, .eu und .org domains. So I suspected that there might be some connection with the hosted TLDs. **However**, we **also host a .net** domain.

reboot does not help. `sudo systemd-resolve --flush-caches` does not help. I noticed that the DNS cache size always remains at 1 and did not reach 0.

Any ideas where I could search the cause of this bug?

Since the behaviour of **nslookup/dig** on the one side and **ping/dnspython** on the other side is different, one could assume that (at least a slightly) different OS API access is used in these cases. Any hint to these differences would also be helpful.

Comment: Hello. Cause I have no idea but if you think it is a bug you can report it. https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/report-ubuntu-bug.html.en

Comment: Which nameservers are you using? Some ISPs are known to output "fake" IPs for nonexistent domains which essentially lead to a spam page for their services.

Comment: Hi muru, this is an interesting thought! Therefore I edited my question to also consider this aspect. Considering the results of my experiments however, the advertisement hypothesis tends to look rather implausible to me.